# Passing multiple parameters into SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

I have a stored procedure that I need to pass multiple parameters in SQL Server 2012. My application will build a report for all employees or certain employees. I have a check list box for the employees if the user wants to choose certain employees instead of all of them. I want to use those selected employees in the where clause in the stored procedure. I've read in SQL Server 2012 you can pass a table as a parameter with multiple values. I can't seem to find a good example to fit my situation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See:  [Sql Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you are passing EmployeeIDs, and they are integers. First, create a table type in the database:

```sql
CREATE TYPE dbo.EmployeesTVP AS TABLE(EmployeeID INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Now your stored procedure can say:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetEmployees
  @empTVP dbo.EmployeesTVP READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT EmployeeID, Name FROM dbo.Employees AS e
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @empTVP WHERE EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID);
END
GO
```

And if you want to handle the *all* scenario, you can say:

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @empTVP)

  SELECT EmployeeID, Name FROM dbo.Employees AS e
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @empTVP WHERE EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID);

ELSE

  SELECT EmployeeID, Name FROM dbo.Employees;
```

(You could combine these with an `OR` conditional, but I tend to find this just gives the optimizer fits.)

Then you create a DataTable in your C# code from the checkboxes, and pass the parameter to your stored procedure as a parameter type of `Structured`. You can fill in the rest but:

```
DataTable tvp = new DataTable();

// define / populate DataTable from checkboxes

using (connectionObject)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetEmployees", connectionObject);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlParameter tvparam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empTVP", tvp);
    tvparam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
    // ... execute the cmd, grab a reader, etc.
}
```

Comment: That is close. I'm going to have to do this in my stored procedure:
where empName like "parameter"
or empName like "parameter1"

Comment: @grath Ok, same concept, can you adapt it? You question made it sound like you were either passing one or more employee IDs, or none.

Comment: So all I have to do to declare it is this :
Create procedure dbo.......
@EmpTVP dbo.EmployeeTVP readonly
,@othervariable
,@othervariable
as
select ....

Answer (score 0):

Complementary to the Aaron response:

1/ Send your data packed as XML and use an XML data type for your parameter

or

2/ Join your employee IDs values into a single string, comma separated, then [split](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/best-split-function-tsql-delimited) those values.